# How to upload Video to YouTube using Google API PHP Client Library and Youtube API V3?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

Trying to simply upload video using [Google API PHP Client (latest release 1.1.6)](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases), but [code in Youtube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video) is not working and giving 500 internal server error.

What is wrong with code below when I am not using any bleeding edge beta version, I have just masked 3 parameters below otherwise it is copied form [Youtube API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video).

```
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

  session_start();

  $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'CHANGE1-0osfh0p5h80o9ol2uqtsjq5i7r1jun.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CHANGE2azMpt__VdSt9';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
  $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
  $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
      FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
      die('The session state did not match.');
    }

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
  }

  if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
  }

  // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
  if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try{
      // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
      $videoPath = "/CHANGE3/videos/test.mp4";

      // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
      // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
      // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
      // video category.
      $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
      $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
      $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
      $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

      // Numeric video category. See
      // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
      $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

      // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
      // "private" and "unlisted".
      $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
      $status->privacyStatus = "public";

      // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
      $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
      $video->setSnippet($snippet);
      $video->setStatus($status);

      // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
      // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
      // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
      $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

      // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
      // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
      $client->setDefer(true);

      // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
      $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

      // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
      $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
          $client,
          $insertRequest,
          'video/*',
          null,
          true,
          $chunkSizeBytes
      );
      $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


      // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
      $status = false;
      $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
      while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
      }

      fclose($handle);

      // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
      $client->setDefer(false);


      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
          $status['snippet']['title'],
          $status['id']);

      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } else {
    // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = <<<END
    <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
    <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
  END;
  }
  echo $htmlBody;
```

**A service error occurred:** `Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UpXd4UQ0dt-v2_8YLzDp4KAywZQUIgUEm3Lxyv7nV_ZLAHghu6RiNE0e82xMMGx9ztQvTdYGFwvSNP5yJiOdffS0CuG-Q: (400) Failed to parse Content-Range header.`

*Don't mark it duplicate of very old and deprecated questions below, as you can see other questions even included files in their code that are not present in latest [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library or are referring to dead Google Code Project. Similar outdated question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042509/is-there-a-way-to-upload-videos-to-youtube-using-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786140/upload-video-into-youtube-channel-through-php-script), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177266/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php-client-library-v3), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236502/upload-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-api-v3-and-php), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189688/uploading-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-v3-and-google-api-client-php)*

Comment: Have you taken an eye on this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

Comment: Yes my code above is exact same code, but it is giving error

Comment: In my case, the problem was the file (for some reason) was not there to be uploaded.. So check first if the file exists.. that cause that error too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely a very small tweak in code fixes the problem.

Instead of just `$videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";` using DOCUMENT_ROOT solves the issue. Other than that code of documentation is perfect.

```
$videoPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mapapp/videos/test.mp4";
```

Answer (score 2):

for other whoe comes around and deal with "Failed to parse Content-Range header"

I was searching for 3 days and finaly i found my solution...

my file was bigger then 4gb and xampp on windows (my webserver tool) is just 32bit so the fopen() command could not read my big files.

I installaed apache 64bit and php7 64bit by my own and it is gone

At this moment my script finaly loads chunks on big files

```
794 - 07:14:15 - 832569344
795 - 07:14:16 - 833617920
796 - 07:14:17 - 834666496
797 - 07:14:18 - 835715072
798 - 07:14:19 - 836763648
799 - 07:14:19 - 837812224
800 - 07:14:20 - 838860800
801 - 07:14:21 - 839909376
802 - 07:14:22 - 840957952
803 - 07:14:23 - 842006528
804 - 07:14:24 - 843055104
```

allready 804 chunks ^^ no truncate nothign :D just uploading flawless

Comment: Plus 1 for the note about using 64bit server components - did the trick.