# Uploading video to youtube API V3 without prompting user login

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am developing App where my clients will be able to upload videos from their Android phones.All videos will be uploaded in the same declared account in code.I have been searching for hours on how i can upload video to youtube without prompting user login,I am currently using [Youtube direct lite](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) which i think is the best option for this task. Is there any source i can refer for API V3 which has used static username and password for authentication?

I have update the code from the link above to make it work with latest android versions,see [here](https://github.com/alfredmack/YouTube-Video-Uploader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to answer my own question after many hours searching for a solution ,Actually there is no proper way of uploading a video to Youtube using API V3 without prompting user's login,This was possible using API V2 which is no longer supported,For that case you wont be able to declare your static username and password.It is advised to use server-side language like PHP to do this for you.You can please refer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954443/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-using-google-api-php-client-library-and-youtube-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) question on how to do that.